# how can we take left value from string value using RDLC expression?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, rdlc

Scenario:
I have text : 12f Country code 
1. I want 12f with bold using rdlc expression how can i do that?
I am using visual studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Left` or `Right` function which returns a string containing a specified number of characters from the left/right side of a string.

Example: `=Left(Fields!MyText.Value,3)`

To get the text in bold you could use CSS but then you'll have to make sure you're using the `HTML markup` type in the Placeholder Properties:

[image]

In the end your expression could look something like this:

```
="<b>" + Left(Fields!MyText.Value,3) + "</b>" + Right(Fields!MyText.Value,3)
```

Comment: #Ocean# thx for replying but i m using Visual studio 2005, in that HTML markup type in the Placeholder Properties not supporting. any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: #Oceans# thx for replying but i m using Visual studio 2005, in that HTML markup type in the Placeholder Properties not supporting. any other way to achieve the same.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using VS 2005 , I'd definitely recommend updating t a newer version, (t least VS 2010. You can even get the free community VS 2013 from here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx